Alsa duplicate speaker sound to HDMI
I'm seeking for help or advice to setup my audio on my linux machine.
I would like to duplicate the audio coming out from the speaker to hdmi output.
Please see the settings I have:
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC662 rev3 Digital [ALC662 rev3 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, Generic Digital
    HDMI Audio Output
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC662 rev3 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output

and the

asound.conf

pcm.!default{
 type plug
 slave.pcm "speakerphat"
}

ctl.!default {
 type hw card 1
}

pcm.speakerphat {
  type softvol
  slave.pcm "plughw:1"
  control.name "Master"
  control.card 1
}

The sound has been enabled by for the speakers:
amixer -q sset 'Master' unmute
amixer -q sset 'IEC958' unmute


Solution alsa-only (I mean no sound server) ? If so, a multi plugin and a couple of bindings should do the trick. I'll elaborate in case of a positive answer to my question.

This answer standing as a possible working answer in the context of an alsa-only sound system.
All pieces of code hereafter should be catenated and replace your existing asound.conf definitions.
All of this could be made much shorter by cascading definitions. However, the magic would be harder to understand and the debugging even more… ;-)

Lets start defining the rate converter to be used in case of resampling needed (dmix resamples when needed)
defaults.pcm.rate_converter "speexrate_best"

Then mainly define aliases to devices. nonblock allowing several applications to open the associated device concurrently.
pcm.ALC662{
        type hw
        card Generic
        device 1
        subdevice 0
        nonblock true}
ctl.ALC662{
        type hw
        card Generic}
pcm.ATI{
        type hw
        card HDMI
        device 0
        subdevice 0
        nonblock true}
ctl.ATI{
        type hw
        card HDMI}


Let's now proceed with dmix plugin definition (enabling mixing of multiple sound sources & resampling when needed). One for each sound output device.
Note the ipc_key (shared memory identifier). Choose whatever unique number. (check first firing sudo ipcs -ma)
Also note that still documented as needed, I just realize now on my system that specifying the ipc_key is just useless. Probably some upgrade that dropped use of sysV-like ipcs behind of my back…?
Also feel free to adapt period_size & buffer_size according to your latency requirements & system capabilities…
pcm.analog {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 219345
    slave{
        pcm ALC662
        format S32_LE
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096 }}

pcm.hdmi {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 219346
    slave{
        pcm ATI
        format S32_LE
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096 }}


Now comes the magic : Combining multiple (stereo v.g. 2 channels) streams to one (stereo v.g. 2 channels) thanks to the multi plugin :
pcm.analogHDMI {
    type multi
    slaves.a.pcm "analog"
    slaves.a.channels 2
    slaves.b.pcm "hdmi"
    slaves.b.channels 2

    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
    bindings.2.slave b
    bindings.2.channel 0
    bindings.3.slave b
    bindings.3.channel 1}


That's it ? Hmmm well… not yet :

Note that the resultant pcm is not in the interleaved format
but in the "complex" format. Hence, it's not accessible by
applications which can handle only the interleaved (or the
non-interleaved) format. In such a case, wrap this PCM with route or
plug plugin.

WILCO, let's route channels (source.destination volume) :
pcm.2in1 {
    type route
    slave.pcm "analogHDMI"   
    ttable.0.0 1
    ttable.1.1 1
    ttable.0.2 1
    ttable.1.3 1}

Of course, if you want this to be the default alsa output then you'll need to add :
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "2in1"}

For further reference.
