Pulseaudio combined sinks resulting in latency & poor audio quality
I want to be able to hear sound from 3 different devices.
I have the following cards.
pactl list cards
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 1
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5460, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.usb-BurrBrown_from_Texas_Instruments_USB_AUDIO_DAC-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 2
    Profiles:
        output:analog-mono: Analog Mono Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 200, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo

The profiles I want to be able to use are
output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo (Current Active Profile) in Card 0

output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo in Card 0

output:analog-stereo in Card 1 

Which from aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: DAC [USB AUDIO    DAC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

would mean hw:0,0 (analog), hw:0,3 (hdmi) & hw:1,0 (usb).
I'm currently testing by combining 2 sinks from Card 0 - hw:0,0 & hw:0,3
Before making any changes this was the state of the system
pactl info
Server String: /var/run/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 32
Server Protocol Version: 32
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 0
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: pulse
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 10.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: a0ec:1eec

This produced sound
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
And this did not produce any sound
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
I changed the defaults like this
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=analog
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=analog,hdmi
pactl set-default-sink combined

This is the new state of my system
pactl info
Server String: /var/run/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 32
Server Protocol Version: 32
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 39
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: pulse
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 10.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: combined
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo
Cookie: a0ec:1eec

Now both of these produce sounds from the correct devices
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

I'm also using gstreamer to set up the pipeline and have updated my "out_sink" to "combined"
out_sink = gst_element_factory_make ("pulsesink", "out_sink");
g_assert_nonnull (out_sink);
g_object_set (out_sink, "device", "combined", NULL);

Now I try testing the audio from the actual app/device
Here I only hear sound from hw:0,0 when it is connected. The audio seems fine. There is no latency for the short period I've tested.
When I disconnect hw:0,0, I hear a delayed audio from hw:0,3. Not only is it delayed but I don't hear all the audio. It sounds broken, like packets have been dropped.
So my questions I suppose are

Why is hw:0,0 prioritized over hw:0,3? Is it based on the priorities as listed in the Card 0 profiles? Is there a way to change that?
How do I ensure that the latency and the quality of the audio is the same through all the devices? When I have only 1 device as the sink there is no problem with the quality or the latency. So why has that changed and how do I fix it?
I'm fairly new to these concepts so is there specific documentation I can check out for more info.


Puilseaudiio has never been the right sound server when low latency is needed. Anyway. I suggest you first try with 2 combined output adapting the answer I posted here  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775070/alsa-duplicate-speaker-sound-to-hdmi/775172#775172 and if satisfied with the result and need help extending to 3, I can help.

@MC68020 Thank you for the suggestion. This looks like I'll have to make changes to my alsa config? I'm not entirely familiar with these concepts so I'm not sure how changing this will help my pulseaudio setup. If there is some literature I could look into about the connection that'd be helpful in understanding the solution you've shared.

1/ I'm afraid there is no other official documentation than what I linked to as "reference" in my other contribution. 2/ Yes, all your alsa raw config will have to be changed. 3/ And of course… all your pulse config as well… if… if… you make the decision to keep pulse… ;-)

@MC68020 Lol. I've been reading up on how newer systems use PipeWire. So maybe I should rethink Pulseaudio since I'm still in the process of setting things up. Thanks anyway. I'll need to do a bit of studying before proceeding.

While you are learning, first ask for why you would need whatever sound server at all. That sort of tool will always increase latency. Best in class (geared toward real time audio and lowest possible latency) as always been jackd. And even its (most reknown) author acknowledges that it is no longer needed. So… read and wonder : Why would you need a sound-server ? (vs everything direct to and from alsa I mean)

@MC68020 Hmmmm I'm trying to setup a RTC system. I did start with jackd but the audio quality was not the best (lots of crackling) which is why I started looking into other servers..
